# A sql query to get all the records where 5 columns are same but only one column is different

Tags: sql, sql-server, redundancy

I have this table:

```
A   B   C   D
1  Cat XYZ 12
1  Cat XYZ 13
1  Dog XYZ 14
2  Dog ABC 15
2  Dog ABC 16
3  Cat XYZ 17
```

Result set:

```
A   B   C   D
1  Cat XYZ 12
1  Cat XYZ 13
2  Dog ABC 15
2  Dog ABC 16
```

I need all such records in my table where A, B, C should be same and the D column can vary. 
Please help it soon that's why asking for help.

Comment: That is 4 columns

Answer (score 3):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.* 
from table t
where exists (select 1
              from table t1
              where t1.a = t.a and t1.b = t.b and t1.c = t.c and t1.d <> t.d
              );
```

Comment: @Jini You state D *can* vary

Comment: Hi Yogesh, won't this ignore rows where all 4 columns (a,b,c,d) are the same. OP said D *can* vary, not sure if it must vary for it to be present in the results.

Comment: @Jini Mabe is worked on the posted data but on you stated requirement.  If you had two 3  Cat XYZ 17 would you want the reported or not?

Comment: @paparazzo No, I wouldn't want that as it is redundant data and this query didn't return the records only occurring once. I got the expected results.

Comment: That query would NOT report two  3 Cat XYZ 17.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want one column to be different, you would need to decide on what value of **Column D** you want to be chosen.

```
SELECT A, B, C, MAX(D) D
FROM table
GROUP BY A, B, C
```

In the above solution, I went the the **maximum** value of column **D**.

Comment: This wouldn't give the same result as they are expecting

Comment: OP stated that the one column (*D*) is different. So, although the sample data seems to identify same value for column D, grouping all columns would conflict with the question.

Comment: if you group by all the columns then they will result it two separate rows in the result because column D is different

Comment: correct. Looks like we differ on the interpretation of the question. 
my understanding is that the data set contains rows that are identical when from columns **A**, through **C**, but different for column**D**.

Comment: Very true -- rereading the question right now looks like they dont even have all potential groupings in their results

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the a, b, c values, you can use aggregation:

```
select a, b, c, min(d), max(d)
from t
group by a, b, c
having min(d) <> max(d);
```

If you want the actual rows, then Yogesh's solution with `exists` is probably the best approach, assuming none of the column values are `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
select * 
from ( select a, b, c, d, 
       count() over (partition by a, b, c) cnt
       from t1
     ) t 
where t.cnt > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Should be able to do this with a simple group by

```
SELECT A, B, C, D
FROM table
GROUP BY A, B, C, D
```

Comment: Does not produce the desired results

Comment: I'm not sure OPs result set is complete -- where is the `A = 3` record?

Comment: A = 3 does not meet the criteria.  Your answer does not produce the desired results.

Comment: based on this description it does -- `I need all such records in my table where A, B, C should be same and the D column can vary`

Comment: It is clear enough to me.  There is no other record with A, B, C the same.  For the 3rd time your query does not produce the desired results.